# Условие если <input> содержит файл php

Tags: php, fileupload

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть тег `<input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />`
Как сделать условие php если input имеет файл.
Вопрос так и не решен. Кто нибудь, помогите...

Comment: По идее так `if($_FILES)`

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров точно, спасибо большое.

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров Не срабатывает если файла в input нет

Comment: `Как сделать условие php если input имеет файл.` А как должно быть?

Comment: Выведите `$_FILES` когда файл есть и когда нет и найдите разницу.

Comment: @u_mulder Если есть файл: array(1) { ["upload"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(54) "Новый текстовый документ (2).txt" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "text/plain" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "/tmp/php96bpzr" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(94) } } }

Comment: @u_mulder Если нет файла: array(1) { ["upload"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(4) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } } }

Comment: Ну теперь напишите условие проверки

Comment: @u_mulder а проверять по какому элементу? Можете помочь?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решил проблему данным кодом:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['upload']['name'][0])) {
/* код */
}
else {
/* код 2 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Изначально форма должна передавать не только данные полей, но и файлы.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="скрин PHP" method="POST">
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php (здесь хорошо расписано)

Затем на сервере проверять наличие файла.

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES)) {
    foreach ($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'] as $file) {
        echo '<li>' . $file . '</li>';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: не работает данный код

Answer (score 0):

Изначально форма должна передавать не только данные полей, но и файлы.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="скрипт PHP" method="POST">
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что моя форма не такая как вы написали?)

Comment: ну вы ж ее не написали, а ошибка отсутствия файла может быть вызвана на этапе передачи. а проверку наличия файла можете сделать по размеру или временному имени файла. 

также можете проверить по коду ошибки передачи. как раз в массиве он у вас есть error = 4. а 4 - Файл не был загружен. http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.errors.php